# Django rest framework create or update in POST resquest

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

can anyone help please, with DRF

according to POST request, I want to create(if not exists) or update() table

belows are my codes

model.py

```
class User1(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    logon_data = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User1
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from .models import User1
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def UserView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User1.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        users = User1.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', views.UserView),
]
```

**when POST request, I want to check like this:**

```
if user exists:
  if user.full_name == request.fullname
     update (user.logon_data)
     save()
  else:
     update (user.full_name)
     update (user.logon_data)
     save()
else:
  create(
       user = request.user,
       full_name = request.full_name,
       logon_data = request.logon_date)
  save()
```

POST request for JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "user": "testuser1",
        "full_name": "test user1",
        "logon_data": "2022-10-19 09:37:26"
    },
    {
        "user": "testuser2",
        "full_name": "test user2",
        "logon_data": "2022-10-20 07:02:06"
    }
]
```

Comment: Its wrong, for create and update the request type should be `PUT`

Comment: with PUT request, it updates by ID one by one, I send mass data with POST and at the same time it should create or update according to mass JSON data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def UserView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User1.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        # if serializer validation fails, raises error by itself
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        for data in serializer.validated_data:
            # checking if data exists else creating an object in User1 model
            # user = data['user'] --> filter to check if that user exist
            # defaults={'full_name': data['full_name'], 'logon_data': #data['logon_data']} --> value provided in defaults is used to update data in #model once the condition is met.
            User1.objects.update_or_create(user=data['user'], defaults={'full_name': data['full_name'], 'logon_data': data['logon_data']})
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
```

Comment: Thanks shiva bahadur basnet,
it worked, 
and one more question, can we make **logs** for this POST requests
I mean I want to keep and write logs in a csv file every day showing which user created

Comment: Welcome, brother. Do you want to first store it on the database or directly write on some CSV files?@Jonibek

Comment: oooh, u did not understand me
it actually saves in database,
I just want to save logs for POST request, I mean how many post requests were in a day, showing user created or updated,
it is just for monitoring

Comment: I have not worked with files much brother. But I am sure there must be a way to do that.@Jonibek

Comment: Thanks Bro, I have found out how to do this, there is a package in django called **drf_api_logger**
https://pypi.org/project/drf-api-logger/
I used it, it is very informative

Answer (score 0):

Try this `update_or_create` it will check based on request.user whether it exists in table or not
Also ensure that `request.user` is checked to user object if you want to check specific field then it should be `request.user.user`

```
User.objects.update_or_create(user=request.user.user, defaults={"full_name": request.full_name, "logon_date":request.logon_date})
```

Comment: hi, how it works, I have put this in my code after **if serializer.is_valid()**:
and got this error
'Request' object has no attribute 'full_name'

Comment: Put this in your POST request where you want to check, It will create if the record is not existing in table\